# How to temporary save database updates before approval from administrator in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

My problem is the following: I am developing a collaborative website in Django where every user can make changes in the database. Say I have a model `MyModel` as follows

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
   description = models.TextField()
```

and, I have an HTML form somewhere that displays the two fields and that every user can access to make changes.

What I would like to do is that every time a user submits a change for an instance of `MyModel`, this update is saved somewhere temporary. Then, when the administrator logs in, he/she can see the submitted updates and can approve them or not.

Here is an idea of how it could work. Let my `MyModel`'s table look like that:

```
+-----+------------+---------------+
| Id  |    Name    |  Description  |
+-----+------------+---------------+
|  1  | AAA        | One instance  |
+-----+------------+---------------+
|  2  | BBB        | Another one   |
+-----+------------+---------------+
```

Now suppose a user would like to change the description of the first instance to change it to ''The first instance''. I would like to record somewhere that there is a modification request for the instance of Id 1 that is change the description to "The first instance".

I have been thinking of several ways to do that:

- Creating a dedicating `EditToMyModel` model where the edits are saved. But that would duplicate a lot of information and also is not very convenient, especially since I want to do that for several models.
- Adding some fields to `MyModel` so that edits are stored in the same table. That would for instance require to have a boolean field isEdit and a ForeignKey on `MyModel` that links an edit to its initial instance.

I am not really satisfied with both of these approaches. If anyone has done something similar or have an idea, that would be great :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a `is_verified` field? The admin can check all of the instances where this is `False` and approved instances can be set to `True`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
   description = models.TextField()
   is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought about doing that but one problem I see is that every edit refers to a given instance, so I would also have to have a foreign key pointing to the initial instance. Maybe this is too much of a machinery in the end ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, is there a model for edits made by an admin? Perhaps you could share more of your code?